# git apply over existing file

Tags: git, apply

I am using git apply to apply a patch over a codebase.

Before triggering this, I apply another command that creates the files that did not have a previous version (I need to trigger this command because it also does other things behind the scene).

The problem is that the patch file also contains a "create" instructions which makes the patch application fail because the file was already created. I cannot erase the already created file.

Is there an "ignore" parameter of some sort that if it cannot create the file because it already exists, it tries to add the content to this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [--exclude](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#git-apply---excludeltpath-patterngt) As I understand, you know, which files were just created, as you are creating them, so just exclude them from applying a patch.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the file is already created, is it created as an empty file, meaning that you want the patch apply to skip the create step, but still fill the file out as if it had created it?

If so, the simplest way is to edit your patch file, and change the patch instructions from file create to those for inserting the data into an empty file.

The specifics of this depend on the patch format, but it should be easy to work out the required changes by producing a patch between an empty file and a file with data, and then writing a script to alter your patch file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With git, you can use 3-way merge with command line option [-3way](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---3way). This will try to merge your patch file into the current source tree even when the file exists and the patch instruction specifies that it is a new file.

Sample Usage:

```
git apply -3way <patch-file>
```